# How to continually get char from keyboard without a pause?

Tags: c, linux, terminal, curses

I'm using `ncurses` to make a game. I tried `getch()`. When I press a key on the keyboard and don't release it, I can get a sequence of the same char. Here comes the question. There is a small pause between the first char and the second char. I'd like to know how to remove the pause between them and continually get chars from when I press the key. Maybe something like KeyDown in windows programming.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A random shot in the dark from what I recall of curses, but does raw(); change the behavior in any favorable way?